# Filter the attributes of an object to return only the ones of a certain type

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to figure out a way to filter an object to get only the attributes of a certain type.

My object looks like this :

```
analysis: {
  cultural1: true,
  cultural2: false,
  cultural3: true,
  cultural4: true,
  culturalScore: 75,
  environment1: true,
  environment2: true,
  environment3: true,
  environment4: true,
  environmentScore: 100,
  createdAt: "2021-09-15 11:43:58 -0400",
  id: 543,
  review: 'Lorem ipsum odor'
}
```

What I want is to get an array of only the boolean attributes of that object.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `Object.entries` to get an array of `key,values` pair and then filter those values based on their types using `typeof`.

```js
let analysis =  {
  cultural1: true,
  cultural2: false,
  cultural3: true,
  cultural4: true,
  culturalScore: 75,
  environment1: true,
  environment2: true,
  environment3: true,
  environment4: true,
  environmentScore: 100,
  createdAt: "2021-09-15 11:43:58 -0400",
  id: 543,
  review: 'Lorem ipsum odor'
}

let result_obj = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(analysis)
.filter(([k,v]) => typeof(v) === 'boolean'))

console.log(result_obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

- Using [`Object#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), get the list of attributes
- Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), iterate over the above list and return keys with boolean values using [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

```js
const analysis = {
  cultural1: true,
  cultural2: false,
  cultural3: true,
  cultural4: true,
  culturalScore: 75,
  environment1: true,
  environment2: true,
  environment3: true,
  environment4: true,
  environmentScore: 100,
  createdAt: "2021-09-15 11:43:58 -0400",
  id: 543,
  review: 'Lorem ipsum odor'
};

const keysWithBooleanValues = 
  Object.keys(analysis)
  .filter(k => typeof analysis[k] == "boolean");

console.log(keysWithBooleanValues);
```